# Proving an equivalence relation, $a^3\equiv 1 \pmod 9$, in $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I would appreciate help with two steps in solving this problem (self-study) from Ireland & Rosen (3.25)

The problem states: Let $\lambda= 1-\omega \in \mathbb{Z}[\omega]$. And $a\equiv 1\pmod \lambda$

Show $a^3\equiv 1\pmod 9$

The first hint is to show $3= -\omega^2\lambda^2$. This is no problem, multiplying out the RHS and using $\omega^3=1$ and $\omega^2=-\omega -1$

Then using $a\equiv 1\pmod \lambda$, or equivalently $a=1+ b\lambda$, as suggested in another hint, cubing both sides and take that $\pmod \lambda^4$ becomes:

$a^3\equiv1+(b^3-\omega^2 b)\lambda^3\pmod {\lambda^4}$

Here is my first difficulty:

It is suggested to show $\lambda$ (or $1-\omega$) divides $b^3-\omega^2 b$. I have tried numerous attempts, the closest I can get is that it equals $b(b-\omega)(b+\omega)$. But that b stand in my way.

So thanks for help with that.

Then that term will be modded out by $\lambda^4$.

My second problem is how to take $a^3\equiv 1\pmod {\lambda^4}$ to the required:

$a^3\equiv 1\pmod 9$

Using $3= -\omega^2\lambda^2$ again (it was used to get the expression for $a^3$ above) I get $9 = \omega^4 \lambda^4$. And $\omega^4 = \omega$ if that helps. But I would appreciate help getting the desired result.

Thanks.

Comment: You should state from the beginning that $\omega$ is a primitive cube root of $1$, not leave it to us to divine from your workings.

Comment: 1. b is congruent to 0, 1, 2 modulo $\lambda$.  2. $\omega$ is a unit, so divisibility by $\lambda^4$ is the same as divisibility by $\omega \lambda^4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your notations and first calculations, one  gets $a^3 \equiv 1 + (b^3 - \omega^2 b)\lambda^3$ mod $\lambda^4$ because $3 = - \omega^2 \lambda^2$ . But this last relation (or a general criterion for quadratic fields) shows that 3 is totally ramified in the  field $\mathbf Q(\omega)$, whose ring of integers mod $\lambda$ is thus isomorphic to $\mathbf Z /3$ . The residue class mod $\lambda$ of  $(b^3 - \omega^2 b)$   is then $\bar { b^3} - \bar b$ = 0 in $\mathbf Z /3$, i.e. $(b^3 - \omega^2 b)\equiv 0$ mod $\lambda$ , and we get $a^3 \equiv 1$ mod $\lambda^4$. Since   $a^3 – 1$ is in $\mathbf Z$ and 3 is totally ramified (ramification index 2), this means that $a^3 \equiv 1$ mod $3^2$, as desired .

Comment: My apologies, but I think the expression is $(b^3 - \omega^{2} b)$ Thanks. With regards,

Comment: True. I edit the misprint.

Comment: Does that change the remark that the residue class is then $\bar{b^3} -\bar b =0$

Comment: No, not at all, because in (Z/3Z)* every square is 1. Actually, in my head I never "wrote" omega^3, but omega^2. In fact, no power of omega can give trouble because in Z/3Z, the only cubic root of 1 is 1: just list the cubes, or notice that the polynomial x^3 - 1 has a null derivative (but this is overkilling !)